# Finding Geometric Multiplicity and Size of Jordan block of Eigen Value

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Let A be square matrix such that
$$|A-xI|=x^4×(x-1)^2×(x-2)^3$$
If $rank(A^3)=rank(A^4)<rank(A^2)$
then geometric multiplicity of Eigen value 0 is?

I found that rank of A = 9 - dim eigenspace(0).

dim eigenspace(0) given by dim of kernel of $A−0I$, or the dimension
of ker(A).

Since the rank of $A^3 = A^4$ I deduced that there could be a jordan block of size 3 in the matrix. But I could not find a reference to this point anywhere in the internet. Is this a valid inference?

This, if true would make geom multiplicity of zero = 2 and Rank of A = 7

Am I correct on this point.